# If the function $f$ satisfies the equation $f(xf(y)+x)=xy+f(x)$, find $f$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

#### Question

> Let the function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$,and such
>   $$f(xf(y)+x)=xy+f(x)$$
>
> Find all $f(x)$

Let $x=1,y=1$,then
$$f(f(1)+1)=1+f(1)$$
let $f(1)=t$,then
$$f(t+1)=1+t$$

So I guess $$f(x)=x$$ is such it, and I found $f(x)=-x$ is also such it?

Can you help?

I found this simaler problem：**(BMO 1997, 2000)**
$$f(xf(x)+f(y))=y+(f(x))^2,f:R\to R$$
this answer $f(x)=x$ or $f(x)=-x$,

the full solution can see [problme 5](http://imomath.com/index.php?options=341&lmm=0)

Comment: I don't mean to disparage the question at all, but who comes up with such problems??

Comment: this problem is from china BBs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take first $x=u\not =0$. As we have $f(uf(y)+u)=uy+f(u)$, we immediately see that $f$ is surjective.
Let $v$ such that $f(v)=0$. We have:

$$f(xf(v)+x)=xv+f(x)=f(x)$$ hence $xv=0$ for all $x$, and $v=0$. We have thus $f(0)=0$.

There exists $v\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(v)=-1$. We have:

$$f(xf(v)+x)=f(-x+x)=f(0)=0=xv+f(x)$$
Now we have $f(x)=-vx$ for all $x$, and it is easy to see that we have $v=\pm 1$, and we are done.

Comment: It's Nice, why are you consider $f(v)=0$ or $f(v)=-1?$ can you explain  more detail?and why How prove $v=\pm 1?$

Comment: @china math: Well I have made some try to see what I can do, and these values are natural. To see that $v=\pm 1$, use the functional equation when you know that $f(x)=-vx$, you will find that $v^2=1$.

Comment: Oh,Thank you,It Nice answer!